# Post types showing tables...Can I do that?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-type, post-type-support

[image: This is the design I'm trying to make]

Hi everyone!
I have the design of my web and there's a page that it should look like this. I don't know if this is the good way to do it but I'm trying to make custom types that show like "post", and every post should be a table. I tried to write it by myself, with plugins... but nothin works. I don't know why it doesn't show. I made my theme from 0 myself and I think I´'m writting something wrong in my single-veranstaltungen.php page. Any help would be really appreciate. This is driving me crazy! I understand what post types do but I think I'm not writting the code properly to make it work. Thanks!!

Comment: I wish you could help me with understanding German (if it is German), because i can't understand what those values are supposed to be in the table.

Comment: We would need to see some of your code to help figure out what's wrong. If I am understanding right that each post is only a table, maybe the problem is you're missing the standard `<html><body>` type tags required of all webpages. Or maybe there is some error you could find in your PHP error log or with WP_DEBUG.

Comment: Sure, that´s the code that I have in my template> single-veranstaltungen.php      ----->     https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7hJJBR5BEcDZGgxTDBxMXpqQlU?usp=sharing

Comment: The values are date/Time/event/ location. It doesn't shows in the webpage. I'm sure that there is something wrong in my code. I'm a wordpress beginner. Thank's a lot for your replies :)